# BufferedReader readLine return value not understood as string in scala?

Tags: scala, bufferedreader

Although I realize there are native scala ways to do the following, nevertheless it would be insightful to understand the behavior.

For the following code snippet the for loop iterator is not correct:

```
val br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/test.txt"))
val stdin = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/x.txt")
for (line : String <- br.readLine) {
  //    val mys = new String(line)
  stdin.write(line)
  stdin.write('\n')
}
```

The iterator  line gives the following compilation error:

```
scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : String
 required: Char
    for (line : String <- br.readLine) {

            ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`br.readLine` returns a String, the `map` operation on String works on `Char`

`for { line <- br.readLine }`

is same as

`br.readLine.map { line =>`

You may write it like this instead:

```
val br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/test.txt"))
val outfile = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/x.txt")

var line:String = ""

while ({ line = br.readLine() ; line != null } ) {

   outfile.write(line.getBytes)
   outfile.write('\n')
}
```

Comment: I was realizing what you wrote independently .. and testing out my alternate solution. However there is still an issue with "stream already closed" that I am working on.

Comment: OK I had "answered" the question: so pls look there. But if you are able to spot the issue with the closed stream I will award the "correct answer" to you.

Answer (score 0):

After messing further with this two issues were discovered.

A) The "line" needs to be a "var" on a separate declaration as follows:

```
var line:String = ""
for (line <- br.readLine) {
```

B) The for loop is iterating over the individual Characters of the string (not the lines in the input). The correct code is:

```
var line:String = ""
while ({line = in.readLine();  line!= null}) {
```

C) The entire code snippet is now:

```
import java.io._
val br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/test.txt"))
val stdin = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/x.txt")
var line:String = ""
  while ({line = in.readLine();  line!= null}) {
    println(line)
    if (line!=null) {
        stdin.write(line.getBytes)
        stdin.write('\n')
    } else {}
}
br.close
stdin.flush
stdin.close
```

However even this solution ends up with:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:97)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:292)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at .<init>(<console>:46)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
```

And note that the "println" in the for loop is never executed.

Comment: with that fix it works. I will award your answer in any case.

Comment: thanks. also `if (line!=null)` check inside while body is redundant.

Comment: Ah I see. It is the second of two operations, the first of which (the assignment) is not involved in the boolean expression checking of the while loop.

Comment: Yes, because `line = br.readLine` is an assignment which returns `Unit` instead of `String` as is the case in Java.